# JFET switch circuit

Tags: power-electronics, jfet

I want to discharge capacitor when  battery pack is disconnected. Will this work?
In my project I use power source selector IC. Problem is, this IC does not recognize battery reconnection until voltage on C1 falls below certain threshold, and right now discharge time is too long. Hence this circuit. Another option is normally closed optorelay, but JFET seems nicer. If I used it correctly of corse (transistor source to battery negative pole).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flppGW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No it won't work as I believe you want it to because you'll also be trying to discharge BAT1 in series with BAT2. XY problem.

Comment: @Andy aka I think i described the actual problem? I want a circuit to quickly discharge the capacitance at the power input of my device. Also, can you please elaborate on why it wont work?

Comment: Why can't you use the opto-relay for discharging the capacitor directly?